# In nrwl-nx (mono repo) angular app i need a exact clone of project-1 as project-2

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am having an nx angular project. i need a clone of the same app in nx environment.. But the project name should be different.. Is there any command available..

lets consider project-1 in (angular App)
I need exact clone of the project-1 as project-2 in NX environment

How do i make a new clonned Project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.